# Does Electron support 4K USB Video resolution?

Tags: electron, usb, video-streaming, resolution

We are developing a windows application using Electron framework. This application intends to show video streaming from USB Camera. We are using "navigator.mediaDevices" apis to access USB video streams. Problem is Electron application unable work for 4K USB video resolution and throws error.

We are able to see the video stream into Electron application but it works only for lower resolution e.g. 480p and hence the quality is not up to mark. The USB camera can support till 4K resolution. However, when we supply higher resolution it works till 720p but beyond that it gives "OverconstrainedError". (code snippet below for refn)

```
          navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
                video:
                    {

                            width: {
                                exact: usbWidth // works till 1280
                            },
                            height: {
                                exact: usbHeight // works till 720

                            },
                            deviceId: {
                            exact: deviceid
                        },

                    }
            }).then(function (stream) {
                stream.getTracks().forEach(function(track) {
                    console.log(track.getSettings());
            })
```

My question is:

1. Does Electron,which is built on top of Chromium, has any limitations with respect to USB Video resolution ?
2. Can 4K USB Video resolution support exist in Electron app ?
3. Is there any reference code which exist to point us in the right direction ?

Here is the response of the FFMPEG Command:-

```
ffmpeg version N-94112-gbb11584924 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9.1.1 (GCC) 20190621

  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libdav1d --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libmfx --enable-amf --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libopenmpt

  libavutil      56. 29.100 / 56. 29.100

  libavcodec     58. 53.100 / 58. 53.100

  libavformat    58. 28.100 / 58. 28.100

  libavdevice    58.  7.100 / 58.  7.100

  libavfilter     7. 55.100 /  7. 55.100

  libswscale      5.  4.101 /  5.  4.101

  libswresample   3.  4.100 /  3.  4.100

  libpostproc    55.  4.100 / 55.  4.100

[dshow @ 0000016c508c8dc0] DirectShow video device options (from video devices)

[dshow @ 0000016c508c8dc0]  Pin "Capture" (alternative pin name "0")

[dshow @ 0000016c508c8dc0]   vcodec=h264  min s=1920x1080 fps=30 max s=1920x1080 fps=60.0002

[dshow @ 0000016c508c8dc0]   vcodec=h264  min s=1920x1080 fps=30 max s=1920x1080 fps=60.0002

[dshow @ 0000016c508c8dc0]   vcodec=h264  min s=1280x720 fps=30 max s=1280x720 fps=60.0002

[dshow @ 0000016c508c8dc0]   vcodec=h264  min s=1280x720 fps=30 max s=1280x720 fps=60.0002

[dshow @ 0000016c508c8dc0]   vcodec=h264  min s=640x360 fps=30 max s=640x360 fps=60.0002

[dshow @ 0000016c508c8dc0]   vcodec=h264  min s=640x360 fps=30 max s=640x360 fps=60.0002

[dshow @ 0000016c508c8dc0]   vcodec=h264  min s=1280x960 fps=30 max s=1280x960 fps=60.0002

[dshow @ 0000016c508c8dc0]   vcodec=h264  min s=1280x960 fps=30 max s=1280x960 fps=60.0002

[dshow @ 0000016c508c8dc0]   vcodec=h264  min s=1024x768 fps=30 max s=1024x768 fps=60.0002

[dshow @ 0000016c508c8dc0]   vcodec=h264  min s=1024x768 fps=30 max s=1024x768 fps=60.0002

[dshow @ 0000016c508c8dc0]   vcodec=h264  min s=640x480 fps=30 max s=640x480 fps=60.0002

[dshow @ 0000016c508c8dc0]   vcodec=h264  min s=640x480 fps=30 max s=640x480 fps=60.0002

[dshow @ 0000016c508c8dc0]   vcodec=h264  min s=1280x1024 fps=30 max s=1280x1024 fps=60.0002

[dshow @ 0000016c508c8dc0]   vcodec=h264  min s=1280x1024 fps=30 max s=1280x1024 fps=60.0002

[dshow @ 0000016c508c8dc0]   vcodec=h264  min s=1280x800 fps=30 max s=1280x800 fps=60.0002

[dshow @ 0000016c508c8dc0]   vcodec=h264  min s=1280x800 fps=30 max s=1280x800 fps=60.0002

[dshow @ 0000016c508c8dc0]   vcodec=mjpeg  min s=1920x1080 fps=15 max s=1920x1080 fps=30

[dshow @ 0000016c508c8dc0]   vcodec=mjpeg  min s=1920x1080 fps=15 max s=1920x1080 fps=30

[dshow @ 0000016c508c8dc0]   vcodec=mjpeg  min s=1280x720 fps=15 max s=1280x720 fps=30

[dshow @ 0000016c508c8dc0]   vcodec=mjpeg  min s=1280x720 fps=15 max s=1280x720 fps=30

[dshow @ 0000016c508c8dc0]   vcodec=mjpeg  min s=640x360 fps=15 max s=640x360 fps=30

[dshow @ 0000016c508c8dc0]   vcodec=mjpeg  min s=640x360 fps=15 max s=640x360 fps=30

[dshow @ 0000016c508c8dc0]   vcodec=mjpeg  min s=1280x960 fps=15 max s=1280x960 fps=30

[dshow @ 0000016c508c8dc0]   vcodec=mjpeg  min s=1280x960 fps=15 max s=1280x960 fps=30

[dshow @ 0000016c508c8dc0]   vcodec=mjpeg  min s=1024x768 fps=15 max s=1024x768 fps=30

[dshow @ 0000016c508c8dc0]   vcodec=mjpeg  min s=1024x768 fps=15 max s=1024x768 fps=30

[dshow @ 0000016c508c8dc0]   vcodec=mjpeg  min s=640x480 fps=15 max s=640x480 fps=30

[dshow @ 0000016c508c8dc0]   vcodec=mjpeg  min s=640x480 fps=15 max s=640x480 fps=30

[dshow @ 0000016c508c8dc0]   vcodec=mjpeg  min s=1280x1024 fps=15 max s=1280x1024 fps=30

[dshow @ 0000016c508c8dc0]   vcodec=mjpeg  min s=1280x1024 fps=15 max s=1280x1024 fps=30

[dshow @ 0000016c508c8dc0]   vcodec=mjpeg  min s=1280x800 fps=15 max s=1280x800 fps=30

[dshow @ 0000016c508c8dc0]   vcodec=mjpeg  min s=1280x800 fps=15 max s=1280x800 fps=30

[dshow @ 0000016c508c8dc0]   pixel_format=yuyv422  min s=640x480 fps=15 max s=640x480 fps=30

[dshow @ 0000016c508c8dc0]   pixel_format=yuyv422  min s=640x480 fps=15 max s=640x480 fps=30

[dshow @ 0000016c508c8dc0]   pixel_format=yuyv422  min s=640x360 fps=15 max s=640x360 fps=30

[dshow @ 0000016c508c8dc0]   pixel_format=yuyv422  min s=640x360 fps=15 max s=640x360 fps=30

[dshow @ 0000016c508c8dc0]   pixel_format=yuyv422  min s=320x240 fps=15 max s=320x240 fps=30

[dshow @ 0000016c508c8dc0]   pixel_format=yuyv422  min s=320x240 fps=15 max s=320x240 fps=30

[dshow @ 0000016c508c8dc0]   pixel_format=yuyv422  min s=320x180 fps=15 max s=320x180 fps=30

[dshow @ 0000016c508c8dc0]   pixel_format=yuyv422  min s=320x180 fps=15 max s=320x180 fps=30
```

Comment: I bet your camera doesn't actually support 4k with a codec that the underlying browser engine can use.  What camera?  What does FFmpeg tell you for it?

Comment: @Brad above mentioned one is the response we are getting for FFMPEG

Comment: Your camera isn't capable of 4k.